# Find the code that this line is referring to?

Tags: java, netbeans, flickr

This is a batch downloader for images on Flickr. I'm curious about how the program gets the original url, so looking through the source code (Favorites.java line 271) I see this, but I wasn't able to find what it's referring to.

```
        String originalUrl = null;
        try {
            originalUrl = curPhoto.getOriginalUrl();
        } catch (FlickrException e) {
            // if the original url just isn't available, fine. no need
            // to panic.
        }
```

https://github.com/magnusvk/flickrfaves

I'm using Netbeans right now and it's not finding anything when I click on any of the `Navigate > Go To` buttons on `curPhoto`. I'd imagine there's an easy way to find the code that it's referring to, but I don't really know what to search on google to learn how to do it.

My question is, where can I find the code for `curPhoto.getOriginalUrl()` and how should I be finding things like this on my own?

Comment: I'd say two things:  make sure your IDE recognizes the source code as a formal project, and [CTRL + F works just fine in cases like this.](https://github.com/magnusvk/FlickrFaves/blob/master/src/de/vonkoeller/flickrFaves/api/Favorites.java#L223)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they are using [flickrj](http://flickrj.sourceforge.net/) to interface with Flickr.

`curPhoto` is of type `Photo`, and if you look in the imports, `Photo` is imported as `import com.aetrion.flickr.photos.Photo;`.  I did a google search for `com.aetrion.flickr` and it turned up that library.

The documentation for that function can be found [here](http://flickrj.sourceforge.net/api/com/aetrion/flickr/photos/Photo.html#getOriginalUrl())

Comment: Thanks. It appears in the IDE as "Compiled Code", I'm assuming that means there's no way to see how they do it?

Comment: http://flickrj.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/flickrj/api/src/com/aetrion/flickr/photos/Photo.java?revision=1.28&view=markup is the source code for the `Photo` object.